# Taxes in canton Ticino, Switzerland

Tags: taxes, switzerland

I'm trying to figure out how much I would need to pay in taxes if I moved to canton Ticino.

I've found [this informative page](https://www3.ti.ch/DFE/DC/calcolatori/RedditoSostanza.php) from the Ticino authorities (in Italian), but I'm a bit confused as to how to fill it in.

If my family's only source of income will be my salary, filling in this form gives me three different ammounts at Federal, Cantonal and Municipal level. Can I just substract those three ammounts from my yearly gross to figure out how much I'll be taking home or will there be other things I'll have to pay?

I'm filling in my gross salary in all four Reddito boxes (Reddito nel Cantonale, Reddito complessivo, Reddito in Svizzera and Reddito complessivo), not sure if that's the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the tax.  In addition, my annual tax certificate has deductions for:

> 9. Beiträge AHV/IV/EO/ALV/NBUV – Cotisations AVS/AI/APG/AC/AANP – Contributions OASI/DI/IC/UI/NBUV
> 10. Beruﬂiche Vorsorge/2. Säule - Prévoyance professionnelle/2e pillier - Company pension plan/2nd pillar
>
> 10.1 Ordentliche Beiträge – Cotisations ordinaires – Regular contributions

The first line is the social security contributions (so, entitlement to unemployment payments etc).  The next two is the mandatory pension contributions.

Apart from that, you will have to pay a health insurance company (*Krankenkasse* in German - I don't know the Italian) for your health insurance. Health insurance is compulsory, and if you haven't picked a company after three months, the canton will pick one for you. Alternatively, if you need medical treatment before that, you will be forced to choose a company.  In any event, premiums will be back-dated to the point that you arrived in Switzerland.

Comment: So, the social security and pension contributions have to be paid on top of whatever Federal/Cantonal/Local tax?

Comment: @DiegoSánchez Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

"the social security and pension contributions" those are part of the social taxes, in Switzerland, like in France your income taxes come after your net salary.

Net = Gross - social taxes.

Then you have to pay your income taxes which are divided in 3 parts: Confederation, Canton, Commune (municipality / local taxes).